# TypeError TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable while developing a web app with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I got an error "TypeError TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable" when I jump to a link and the code for the route is below.

```py
@app.route("/aq", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def questionnaire():
    global answers_df, merged_df, id_to_answers
    answers_df = pd.DataFrame()
     
    if request.method == "POST":
        action = request.form.get("action")
        new_answers = {"QID": [], "Answer1": []}
        for key in request.form:
            question_id = key
            new_answers["QID"].append(question_id)
            new_answers["Answer1"].append(request.form.get(question_id, ""))
        new_answers_df = pd.DataFrame(new_answers)
        answers_df = pd.concat([answers_df, new_answers_df], ignore_index=True)
        merged_df = df_config.merge(answers_df, on='QID', how='outer',suffixes=('_load', ''))

        if action == 'save':
           # save the dataframe to local
    return render_template("questionnaire.html", submitted = False)
```

I found the problem is related to render_template. But I don't know how to fix it.

The trace back is here

```
TypeError
TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Projects\IRQ Tools\app.py", line 134, in questionnaire
return render_template("questionnaire.html")
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 137, in render_template
return _render(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 120, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1090, in render
self.environment.handle_exception()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Projects\IRQ Tools\templates\questionnaire.html", line 187, in top-level template code
var defaultOptions = {{ givenanswers | tojson }};
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 376, in tojson_filter
return Markup(htmlsafe_dumps(obj, **kwargs))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 290, in htmlsafe_dumps
dumps(obj, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 211, in dumps
rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
return cls(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 100, in default
Open an interactive python shell in this framereturn _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

The html works and report.html also works with another app. So, I assume it's something wrong with this part.

Please help me solve the error I got.

Comment: I'd say welcome to Stack Overflow, but it appears you're not new. Maybe it has been a while since you've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please post the full traceback so we can see where the error happens.

Comment: It looks like `{{givenanswers | tojson }}` is causing the problem because it's not json serializable. Did you use `dump(givenanswers)` to see what that object is?